# Javascript error when creating form elements

Tags: javascript, forms

Error:

uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsIDOMHTMLSelectElement.appendChild]" nsresult: "0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/midas/index.php/submit/displayform ::  :: line 104" data: no]

The code is meant to create:

textboxt - textbox - textbox - pulldown - textbox

Here is the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  var ta=new Array();
  var n=15;
window.onload=function()
{
   inp=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(c=0;c<inp.length;c++) 
    {
        if(inp[c].value=='add') 
        {
           inp[c].onclick=function() 
            {
                var ta = [];
                var n = 15;

               ta[n]=document.createElement('input');
               ta[n].setAttribute('rows',1);
               ta[n].setAttribute('cols',20);
               ta[n].name='time'+n;
               document.getElementById('txtara').appendChild(ta[n])
               ta[n]=document.createElement('input');
               ta[n].setAttribute('rows',1);
               ta[n].setAttribute('cols',20);
               ta[n].name='event'+n;
               document.getElementById('txtara').appendChild(ta[n])
               ta[n]=document.createElement('input');
               ta[n].setAttribute('rows',1);
               ta[n].setAttribute('cols',20);
               ta[n].name='supplies'+n;
               document.getElementById('txtara').appendChild(ta[n])

                var sel = document.createElement('select');



                ta[n]=document.createElement('option');
                ta[n].value = 'YES';
                ta[n].name='success'+n;
                ta[n].innerHTML = ta[n].value;
                n++;
                ta[n]=document.createElement('option');
                ta[n].value = 'NO';
                ta[n].name='success'+n;
                ta[n].innerHTML = ta[n].value;
                n++;

                sel.appendChild(ta[0]);
                sel.appendChild(ta[1]);


                document.getElementById('txtara').appendChild(sel);



               document.getElementById('here').appendChild(sel);
               document.getElementById('txtara').appendChild(ta[n])
               n++;
            }
         }

    }
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating nodes and storing them in `ta[15]` and `ta[16]`, but you're inserting nodes from `ta[0]` and `ta[1]` into the DOM, which don't exist.

do `var n = 0`; instead of `n = 15`.

Comment: Thanks, Im starting at n = 15 because I am using php to create 14 rows and i want the javascript to expand on this if there is not enough for the user. What should I do then?

Comment: Well, either way... look at the work flow. you create two new nodes with `ta[n] = document.Create...`, at which point n is 15 and 16. but then you do `sel.appendChild(ta[0])`, which does not exist in your javascript. There may be equivalent nodes in the document somewhere, but they're not linked into your code at all, so you're essentially trying to `sel.appendChild(null)`.

Comment: So what should I do to fix it to make sel.appendChild(ta[n]) ?

Comment: Why are you even using an array to hold the new nodes? You could just do `var x = doc.CreateEle(..); ... ; sel.appendChild(x)` without using arrays. re-using `x` for each one won't kill the previously created nodes as long as you do the appendChild() each time BEFORE creating a new node and re-using x.

Comment: Ok I have made some progress however now Im having problems with the pull down menu displaying properly here is the source code:
`code`
<div id="txtara">
<input rows="1" cols="20" name="time15">
<input rows="1" cols="20" name="event15">
<input rows="1" cols="20" name="supplies15">
<select></select>
<option value="NO">NO</option>
</div>

Comment: Its stretched accross the whole screen with only the No option

Comment: Ok it looks like the options are not nested inside the select

Comment: You need to do (in pseudo-code) `x = new Select; x.appendChild(new Option); x.appendChild(new Option)` etc... You're appending the options to the wrong element.

Comment: Ok I fixed it just gave YES the variable name y and No - x